# Yosemite graphic artefacs

Tags: macos, graphics, bug

Recently I was zooming on a picture on Yosemite and I came to this : [image]

Which changed to this :

[image]

When I moved the mouse...

As I changed three time my 2011 15" MBP motherboard this year for GC issues I feared the worst but it seems that I'm not the only one, a few friends told me about this.

Is anyone aware of some potential fix ?

## Log :

```
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC.LidOpen (User)
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
07/11/2014 17:58:10,004 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: assertion failed: 14A389: launchd + 160118 [55B9FF23-B298-321A-B776-CF7676586C04]: 0xe
07/11/2014 17:58:10,002 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 86, ErrLogCount 1 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:10,003 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 86, ErrLogCount 2 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:10,004 watchdogd[311]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 1 milliseconds
07/11/2014 17:58:10,006 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: assertion failed: 14A389: launchd + 160118 [55B9FF23-B298-321A-B776-CF7676586C04]: 0xe
07/11/2014 17:58:10,038 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNSServer:: PowerState is Wakeup
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: TBT W (1): 0 [x]
07/11/2014 17:58:10,137 sharingd[355]: 17:58:10.136 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
07/11/2014 17:58:10,329 WindowServer[159]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [110872658795510]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
07/11/2014 17:58:10,331 WindowServer[159]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Reordering authw 0x7f919c2584a0(2004) (lock state: 3)
07/11/2014 17:58:10,331 WindowServer[159]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: err 0x0
07/11/2014 17:58:10,447 apsd[53]: Peer [pid=328] requested push wake but lacks APSPushWakeEntitlement
07/11/2014 17:58:10,448 identityservicesd[371]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fd04e2223b0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fd04e21c780 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
07/11/2014 17:58:10,470 identityservicesd[371]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fd04e2223b0>:    NC Disabled: NO
07/11/2014 17:58:10,477 identityservicesd[371]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fd04e2223b0>:   DND Enabled: NO
07/11/2014 17:58:10,477 identityservicesd[371]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fd04e2223b0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
))
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'FR'.
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140
07/11/2014 17:58:10,494 SubmitDiagInfo[472]: Couldn't load config file from on-disk location. Falling back to default location. Reason: Won't serialize in _readDictionaryFromJSONData due to nil object
07/11/2014 17:58:10,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Mail(331) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c  MAC AUTH succeeded
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: interface en is sending notification 0x14
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: interface en is coming UP
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
07/11/2014 17:58:11,181 configd[26]: LINKLOCAL en1: parent has no IP
07/11/2014 17:58:11,188 configd[26]: no interface for external service id
07/11/2014 17:58:11,192 networkd[143]: +[NETLedBelly stopFastFail] Clearing ledbelly failure cache
07/11/2014 17:58:11,192 UserEventAgent[17]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
07/11/2014 17:58:11,193 configd[26]: network changed: v4(en1-:192.168.0.25) DNS- Proxy-
07/11/2014 17:58:11,194 vmnet-bridge[20929]: Dynamic store changed
07/11/2014 17:58:11,198 vmnet-bridge[20929]: Failed to read SCproperties for key: State:/Network/Global/IPv4
07/11/2014 17:58:11,198 vmnet-bridge[20929]: Stopping bridge for: en1
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetDisconnect called for port 0xffffff804ddd7c00
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: filter detached
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: down
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: detached
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: Freeing hub at 0xffffff8058550000.
07/11/2014 17:58:11,201 discoveryd[52]: Basic WABServer NetResolverEvent no resolvers, resetting domains
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:11,285 sharingd[355]: 17:58:11.285 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:11,299 sharingd[355]: 17:58:11.299 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetSetopt: Set link state DOWN
07/11/2014 17:58:11,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetSetopt: Set link state UP
07/11/2014 17:58:11,754 EscrowSecurityAlert[916]:  SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle!! 7
07/11/2014 17:58:12,044 discoveryd[52]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStopBrowsingForKey: '_airplay' Browsing service stopped
07/11/2014 17:58:12,044 discoveryd[52]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStopBrowsingForKey: '_raop' Browsing service stopped
07/11/2014 17:58:12,092 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.auditd[49520]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.auditd
07/11/2014 17:58:12,102 thomas[49527]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20141106205454.20141107165812
07/11/2014 17:58:12,102 thomas[49526]: audit warning: soft /var/audit
07/11/2014 17:58:12,102 thomas[49525]: audit warning: allsoft 
07/11/2014 17:58:12,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
07/11/2014 17:58:12,420 discoveryd[52]: Basic Warn DD_Warn: Corrupt NSEC RDATA size
07/11/2014 17:58:12,619 netbiosd[49195]: network_reachability_changed : network is not reachable, netbiosd is shutting down
07/11/2014 17:58:13,149 configd[26]: no interface for external service id
07/11/2014 17:58:13,150 networkd[143]: +[NETLedBelly stopFastFail] Clearing ledbelly failure cache
07/11/2014 17:58:13,151 configd[26]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
07/11/2014 17:58:13,153 UserEventAgent[17]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1709] en1: SSID 'fbx_Atom' making interface primary (cache indicates network not captive)
07/11/2014 17:58:13,153 UserEventAgent[17]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Evaluating
07/11/2014 17:58:13,157 UserEventAgent[17]: Captive: en1: Not probing 'fbx_Atom' (cache indicates not captive)
07/11/2014 17:58:13,158 UserEventAgent[17]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Authenticated
07/11/2014 17:58:13,162 configd[26]: network changed: v4(en1!:192.168.0.25) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
07/11/2014 17:58:13,162 vmnet-bridge[20929]: Dynamic store changed
07/11/2014 17:58:13,164 vmnet-bridge[20929]: Started bridge for 0, en1
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VNetUserIf_Create: created userIf at 0xffffff8043a2aa00.
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetConnect: returning port 0xffffff8043a2aa00
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: Hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: Allocated hub 0xffffff80492d9000 for hubNum 0.
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNET_SO_BINDTOHUB: port: paddr 00:50:56:fd:1a:04
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: Hub 0
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet:   Port 0
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: media 80 dev 0xffffff8045759ab0 family 2
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: wireless interface detected.
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: up
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en1: attached
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VNetUserIfFree: freeing userIf at 0xffffff8043a2aa00.
07/11/2014 17:58:13,167 discoveryd[52]: Basic Sockets,Warn UDS FD=104 ERROR: Send failed errno=32
07/11/2014 17:58:13,168 GeekTool Helper[468]: Geeklet 2FB413A2-E2AF-4FB4-BD29-DD7C0A5660EF. Task already running (ping -c 3 8.8.8.8)
07/11/2014 17:58:13,181 networkd[143]: +[NETLedBelly stopFastFail] Clearing ledbelly failure cache
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:13,183 sharingd[355]: 17:58:13.183 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
07/11/2014 17:58:13,226 BetterTouchTool[49509]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.0 instead of 10.10.0. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
07/11/2014 17:58:13,226 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8b211dc3 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 113
07/11/2014 17:58:13,226 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff91c92c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
07/11/2014 17:58:13,227 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff91c92b26 dispatch_once_f + 117
07/11/2014 17:58:13,227 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8b1ba4da _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 987
07/11/2014 17:58:13,227 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8b1ba0c7 Gestalt + 144
07/11/2014 17:58:13,227 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 5   FeedbackReporter                    0x0000000107a8f20f +[FRCrashLogFinder getSystemVersionMajor:minor:bugFix:] + 47
07/11/2014 17:58:13,227 BetterTouchTool[49509]: 6   FeedbackReporter                    0x0000000107a8f66c +[FRCrashLogFinder findCrashLogsSince:] + 76
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetSetopt: Set link state DOWN
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetSetopt: Set link state UP
07/11/2014 17:58:13,378 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNSServer:: PowerState is Wakeup
07/11/2014 17:58:13,389 watchdogd[311]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
07/11/2014 17:58:13,390 coreaudiod[339]: 2014-11-07 05:58:13.390205 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
07/11/2014 17:58:13,391 sharingd[355]: 17:58:13.390 : Starting AirDrop server for user 501 on wake
07/11/2014 17:58:13,391 coreaudiod[339]: 2014-11-07 05:58:13.390901 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
07/11/2014 17:58:13,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:13,432 sharingd[355]: 17:58:13.432 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
07/11/2014 17:58:11,602 ntpd[244]: wake time set -2.106162 s
07/11/2014 17:58:12,211 GeekTool Helper[468]: Geeklet 2FB413A2-E2AF-4FB4-BD29-DD7C0A5660EF. Task already running (ping -c 3 8.8.8.8)
07/11/2014 17:58:13,575 discoveryd[52]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartBrowsingForKey: '_airplay' Browsing service started
07/11/2014 17:58:13,575 discoveryd[52]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartBrowsingForKey: '_raop' Browsing service started
07/11/2014 17:58:15,956 BetterTouchTool[49536]: setting up yosemite events
07/11/2014 17:58:16,006 BetterTouchTool[49536]: enabling touch for internal trackpad (after clamshell)
07/11/2014 17:58:16,016 BetterTouchTool[49536]: init
07/11/2014 17:58:16,440 BetterTouchTool[49536]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.0 instead of 10.10.0. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
07/11/2014 17:58:16,440 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8b211dc3 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 113
07/11/2014 17:58:16,440 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff91c92c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
07/11/2014 17:58:16,440 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff91c92b26 dispatch_once_f + 117
07/11/2014 17:58:16,440 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8b1ba4da _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 987
07/11/2014 17:58:16,440 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8b1ba0c7 Gestalt + 144
07/11/2014 17:58:16,441 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 5   FeedbackReporter                    0x00000001037d120f +[FRCrashLogFinder getSystemVersionMajor:minor:bugFix:] + 47
07/11/2014 17:58:16,441 BetterTouchTool[49536]: 6   FeedbackReporter                    0x00000001037d166c +[FRCrashLogFinder findCrashLogsSince:] + 76
07/11/2014 17:58:17,210 GeekTool Helper[468]: Geeklet 2FB413A2-E2AF-4FB4-BD29-DD7C0A5660EF. Task already running (ping -c 3 8.8.8.8)
07/11/2014 17:58:27,364 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[49549]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
07/11/2014 17:58:28,121 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 1 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:28,263 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 2 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:28,451 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 3 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:28,451 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 4 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:28,451 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 5 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:28,452 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 6 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:28,843 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 7 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,066 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 8 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,217 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 9 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,362 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 10 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,542 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 11 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,542 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 12 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,543 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 13 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,543 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 14 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:29,869 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 15 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,099 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 16 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,313 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 17 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,451 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 18 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,558 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 19 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,559 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 20 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,559 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 21 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,559 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 22 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:30,943 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 23 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,199 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 24 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,365 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 25 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,542 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 26 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,643 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 27 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,644 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 28 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,644 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 29 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:31,645 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 30 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,043 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 31 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,292 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 32 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,463 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 33 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,642 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 34 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,743 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 35 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,744 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 36 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,744 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 37 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:32,745 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 38 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,133 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 39 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,392 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 40 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,563 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 41 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,741 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 42 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,843 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 43 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,843 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 44 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,844 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 45 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:33,844 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 46 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:34,230 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 47 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:34,493 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 48 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:34,662 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 49 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:34,840 discoveryd[52]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer fe80::225:4bff:fe03:5ff5 Port 58001 errno 65, fd 106, ErrLogCount 50 ResolverIntf:0
07/11/2014 17:58:34,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c  MAC AUTH succeeded
07/11/2014 17:58:34,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
07/11/2014 17:58:34,000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:34,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 6a:8d:77:b8:4f:2c
07/11/2014 17:58:34,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
07/11/2014 17:58:38,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
07/11/2014 17:58:41,000 kernel[0]: en1 duplicate IP address 192.168.0.25 sent from address 00:25:4b:03:5f:f5
07/11/2014 17:58:41,657 configd[26]: DHCP en1: defending IP 192.168.0.25 against BonjourSleepProxy 00:25:4b:03:5f:f5 1 (of 5)
07/11/2014 17:58:45,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: storeuid(14240) deny mach-lookup com.apple.dock.server
07/11/2014 17:59:35,000 kernel[0]: en1 duplicate IP address 192.168.0.25 sent from address 00:25:4b:03:5f:f5
07/11/2014 17:59:35,689 configd[26]: DHCP en1: defending IP 192.168.0.25 against BonjourSleepProxy 00:25:4b:03:5f:f5 1 (of 5)
07/11/2014 18:00:01,157 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.auditd[49606]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.auditd
07/11/2014 18:00:01,167 thomas[49610]: audit warning: allsoft 
07/11/2014 18:00:01,167 thomas[49611]: audit warning: soft /var/audit
07/11/2014 18:00:01,169 thomas[49612]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20141107165812.20141107170001
07/11/2014 18:00:01,202 CoreServicesUIAgent[46188]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7c266c60> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7c266f70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>
07/11/2014 18:00:01,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: storeuid(14240) deny mach-lookup com.apple.dock.server
07/11/2014 18:00:37,054 CoreServicesUIAgent[46188]: Error -60005 creating authorization
07/11/2014 18:00:37,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: storeuid(14240) deny mach-lookup com.apple.dock.server
07/11/2014 18:01:00,000 kernel[0]: en1 duplicate IP address 192.168.0.25 sent from address 00:25:4b:03:5f:f5
07/11/2014 18:01:00,376 configd[26]: DHCP en1: defending IP 192.168.0.25 against BonjourSleepProxy 00:25:4b:03:5f:f5 1 (of 5)
07/11/2014 18:01:48,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: com.apple.metada(381) deny mach-lookup com.apple.cfnetwork.cfnetworkagent
```

Comment: could you publish a Console log for us to see what is ging on before replacing the motherboard again :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 here we go (note that if I need a new motherboard Apple gives me a new MPB(r?) for free)

Comment: So why are we still talking then :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 because I'm not sure that the GC is faulty as it occurs leeeeess often than the 3 last times and I don't want to spend hours waiting in vain in an Apple store

Comment: I understand, so do a test by running in Safe mode which would exclude non apple stuff. Your console log does not say anything about graphics other than your WiFi is located in France :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 nothing very confidential :p i'll try an apple test

Answer (score 1):

The only real fix is replacing the gpu (therefor the motherboard).

There are quite a number of reports about this issue on the internet, example:
http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/01/16/owners-of-late-2011-macbook-pros-report-critical-gpu-failures-system-crashes

You can use a tool like GFX Card Status (https://gfx.io) to force your MacBook to use only the integrated card, not the discrete one (which is usually the fault), but that leaves you with a few problems (such as not being able to use external monitors).

Answer (score 0):

Glad I found this. Not convinced this is the GPU problem. I have the 2010 MBP 6,2, and had the GPU replaced under a special extended warranty last August 2014 by Apple. About a month ago, I got the exact same screens as above. I took it into the Apple Store and they ran a full test, including video. It passed.
For now, I have turned off the "automatically switch graphics" in energy saver. 
If you look at the console logs when this happens, it looks like a kernel panic associated with the Intel chipset. July 1, 2015 (today) I see Apple has released an update that deals with some Intel buffer overflows.
I think this is a Yosemite thing, and not a hardware thing.